# Can you create AWS RDS Aurora tables using CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, amazon-aurora

I'm fairly new to AWS CDK, and I just created an architecture with an Aurora cluster inside of it. Is there a way to initialize a database schema inside of my CDK files? It seems a bit annoying to create the instance and then have to connect through other means in order to set up a schema. My impression of CDK is that you can do everything relating to setting up the services, so I was curious if this is a possibility.

If this isn't possible, can I use a lambda that fires off after the CDK deployment? Or maybe have a snapshot inside of s3? I'm just trying to find the best solution!

Answer (score 10):

You can do this, although it requires you to execute it as a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-cloudformation.CustomResource.html) within the CDK.

You would need to create a Lambda function the performs the SQL DDL tasks for you. This would then return a successful flag back to the execution runtime to say that this "resource" was successfully created.

Comment: What would this look like? Do I initialize a lambda as a custom resource and then run it, or do I intialize a lambda first and then run it as a custom resource?

Comment: The Lambda does not need to be launched ahead of time, an example is here: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/blob/master/typescript/custom-resource/my-custom-resource.ts#L23. The custom resource will launch the Lambda and pass the parameters in.

Comment: There's a blog post with code using the CDK and custom resources here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/use-aws-cdk-to-initialize-amazon-rds-instances/