# How to create tables in Postgres RDS using CDK?

Tags: typescript, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

I created a Postgres RDS database using the CDK. I read the documentation but didn't find a way to create tables through it.

The language I'm using is TypeScript.

Comment: Please, clarify the type of database you'd like to create, – AWS has a ton of options for a database, each of which has to be treated differently

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a RDS table using the CDK or [CloudFormation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52437074/aws-cloudformation-create-tables-after-rds-instance-is-ready/52466828).

You can use the [AWS SDK client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-rds-data/index.html) to execute a `CREATE TABLE...` command against your database.  The SDK client can be used locally or in a [lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-rds-tutorial.html), for instance.

Answer (score 0):

This post might help you. You need to use `CustomResource`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62331465/6741215

Answer (score 0):

There's no AWS CDK support for this. However, I've created a package named [cloudformation-sql-run](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudformation-sql-run)  that helps with that. You can use it as follows:

```
const createPosts = new SqlRun(this, 'Create Posts', {
  vpc: vpc,
  connection: SqlRunConnection.fromDatabaseInstance(db),
  up: {
    run: [{
      sql: `CREATE TABLE posts(name varchar)`
    }, {
      sql: `INSERT INTO posts(name) VALUE (:secret)`,
      parameters: {
        secret: SqlSecret.fromSecretsManager(password)
      }
    }],
  },
  down: {
    run: [{
      sql: `DROP TABLE posts`
    }]
  }
});
```